# Impossible to enable modules in SimpleTest

Tags: testing

I am building SimpleTests for my modules:

It seems like the standard procedure for enabling modules it doesn't work for me:

```
function setUp() {
    parent::setUp('mymodule');
 }
```

I constantly get a stupid error code: `Duplicate entry 'bartik-system-main' for key 'tmd': INSERT INTO {block}`

As I am using profiles I used the $profile variable:

```
protected $profile = 'myprofilename';
```

I have forced this by using a Drupal function:

```
module_enable(array('mymodule'), $enable_dependencies = TRUE);
```

In this final case the error that persists is

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$name
```

Here below is a sample of my code:

```
class mymoduleWebTestCase extends DrupalWebTestCase {

  protected $privileged_user;

  protected $profile = 'myprofile';

  public static function getInfo() {
    return array(
        'name' => 'mymodule',
        'description' => 'mydescription.',
        'group' => 'mygroup',
    );
  }

  function setUp() {
    $this->privileged_user = new stdClass();
    parent::setUp();
   // Login a user that has access to the content sync server admin settings
    $this->privileged_user = $this->drupalCreate();
    $this->drupalLogin($this->privileged_user);
  }

  function testMyModule() {


    //Create content of community type
    $settings = array(
      'type' => 'mycontenttype',
      'title' => 'Sample Content',
      'link' => 'http://www.google.com',
      'body' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('body'))),
      'moderate' => 1,
      'status' => 1,
      'revisions' => NULL,
      'taxonomy' => NULL,
    );
    $node = $this->drupalCreateNode($settings);
    $this->drupalGet('mymodule/sample-content');
    $this->assertRaw('Sample Content', t('Content created.'));


    $node = $this->drupalCreateNode($settings);

   //This if we have a valid link inside
    $this->clickLink(t('http://www.google.com'));

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should make triple-sure that your module declares all of its dependencies properly. Even if it does, Simpletest struggles with dependencies and you may have luck if you enable them explicitly in `setUp()` before your module.

Also, not sure if it's the contributing your error, but instead of `$this->privileged_user = new stdClass();` I would use `DrupalWebTestCase::drupalCreateUser` like so: `$this->privileged_user = $this->drupalCreateUser()`. I might also declare it after `setup()` but I'm not sure that's significant.

Answer (score 0):

The `Duplicate entry 'bartik-system-main' for key 'tmd'` seems to be the same as an error caused by using fe_block module, reported here
[Simpletest: database exception during setUp](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/124776/simpletest-database-exception-during-setup)

The solution proposed for that question was to enable modules after the main setup was complete. It worked for me when I had the same exception. Using an installation profile makes it more difficult, but assuming it is the same case, perhaps there is a way to make a simplified test profile with the features module disabled, and re-enable it manually?