# Simpletest: database exception during setUp

Tags: 7, features, testing

I'm writing lots and lots of test cases for different modules and have come across a rather strange error about which I'm hoping others may have more insight. In my `setUp` function override, the first thing I'm doing is `parent::setUp('my_module')`. Whenever I run a test case that part fails with a PDOException inserting (duplicate) entries into the {block} table. This is the entire stack trace:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'bartik-system-main' for key 'tmd': INSERT INTO {block} (module, delta, theme, status, weight, region, pages, cache) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7), (:db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12, :db_insert_placeholder_13, :db_insert_placeholder_14, :db_insert_placeholder_15), (:db_insert_placeholder_16, :db_insert_placeholder_17, :db_insert_placeholder_18, :db_insert_placeholder_19, :db_insert_placeholder_20, :db_insert_placeholder_21, :db_insert_placeholder_22, :db_insert_placeholder_23), (:db_insert_placeholder_24, :db_insert_placeholder_25, :db_insert_placeholder_26, :db_insert_placeholder_27, :db_insert_placeholder_28, :db_insert_placeholder_29, :db_insert_placeholder_30, :db_insert_placeholder_31), (:db_insert_placeholder_32, :db_insert_placeholder_33, :db_insert_placeholder_34, :db_insert_placeholder_35, :db_insert_placeholder_36, :db_insert_placeholder_37, :db_insert_placeholder_38, :db_insert_placeholder_39), (:db_insert_placeholder_40, :db_insert_placeholder_41, :db_insert_placeholder_42, :db_insert_placeholder_43, :db_insert_placeholder_44, :db_insert_placeholder_45, :db_insert_placeholder_46, :db_insert_placeholder_47), (:db_insert_placeholder_48, :db_insert_placeholder_49, :db_insert_placeholder_50, :db_insert_placeholder_51, :db_insert_placeholder_52, :db_insert_placeholder_53, :db_insert_placeholder_54, :db_insert_placeholder_55), (:db_insert_placeholder_56, :db_insert_placeholder_57, :db_insert_placeholder_58, :db_insert_placeholder_59, :db_insert_placeholder_60, :db_insert_placeholder_61, :db_insert_placeholder_62, :db_insert_placeholder_63), (:db_insert_placeholder_64, :db_insert_placeholder_65, :db_insert_placeholder_66, :db_insert_placeholder_67, :db_insert_placeholder_68, :db_insert_placeholder_69, :db_insert_placeholder_70, :db_insert_placeholder_71), (:db_insert_placeholder_72, :db_insert_placeholder_73, :db_insert_placeholder_74, :db_insert_placeholder_75, :db_insert_placeholder_76, :db_insert_placeholder_77, :db_insert_placeholder_78, :db_insert_placeholder_79), (:db_insert_placeholder_80, :db_insert_placeholder_81, :db_insert_placeholder_82, :db_insert_placeholder_83, :db_insert_placeholder_84, :db_insert_placeholder_85, :db_insert_placeholder_86, :db_insert_placeholder_87), (:db_insert_placeholder_88, :db_insert_placeholder_89, :db_insert_placeholder_90, :db_insert_placeholder_91, :db_insert_placeholder_92, :db_insert_placeholder_93, :db_insert_placeholder_94, :db_insert_placeholder_95); Array
(
[:db_insert_placeholder_0] => system
[:db_insert_placeholder_1] => main
[:db_insert_placeholder_2] => bartik
[:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0
[:db_insert_placeholder_5] => content
[:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_7] => -1
[:db_insert_placeholder_8] => search
[:db_insert_placeholder_9] => form
[:db_insert_placeholder_10] => bartik
[:db_insert_placeholder_11] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_12] => -1
[:db_insert_placeholder_13] => sidebar_first
[:db_insert_placeholder_14] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_15] => -1
[:db_insert_placeholder_16] => node
[:db_insert_placeholder_17] => recent
[:db_insert_placeholder_18] => seven
[:db_insert_placeholder_19] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_20] => 10
[:db_insert_placeholder_21] => dashboard_main
[:db_insert_placeholder_22] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_23] => -1
[:db_insert_placeholder_24] => user
[:db_insert_placeholder_25] => login
[:db_insert_placeholder_26] => bartik
[:db_insert_placeholder_27] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_28] => 0
[:db_insert_placeholder_29] => sidebar_first
[:db_insert_placeholder_30] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_31] => -1
[:db_insert_placeholder_32] => system
[:db_insert_placeholder_33] => navigation
[:db_insert_placeholder_34] => bartik
[:db_insert_placeholder_35] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_36] => 0
[:db_insert_placeholder_37] => sidebar_first
[:db_insert_placeholder_38] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_39] => -1
[:db_insert_placeholder_40] => system
[:db_insert_placeholder_41] => powered-by
[:db_insert_placeholder_42] => bartik
[:db_insert_placeholder_43] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_44] => 10
[:db_insert_placeholder_45] => footer
[:db_insert_placeholder_46] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_47] => -1
[:db_insert_placeholder_48] => system
[:db_insert_placeholder_49] => help
[:db_insert_placeholder_50] => bartik
[:db_insert_placeholder_51] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_52] => 0
[:db_insert_placeholder_53] => help
[:db_insert_placeholder_54] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_55] => -1
[:db_insert_placeholder_56] => system
[:db_insert_placeholder_57] => main
[:db_insert_placeholder_58] => seven
[:db_insert_placeholder_59] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_60] => 0
[:db_insert_placeholder_61] => content
[:db_insert_placeholder_62] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_63] => -1
[:db_insert_placeholder_64] => system
[:db_insert_placeholder_65] => help
[:db_insert_placeholder_66] => seven
[:db_insert_placeholder_67] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_68] => 0
[:db_insert_placeholder_69] => help
[:db_insert_placeholder_70] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_71] => -1
[:db_insert_placeholder_72] => user
[:db_insert_placeholder_73] => login
[:db_insert_placeholder_74] => seven
[:db_insert_placeholder_75] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_76] => 10
[:db_insert_placeholder_77] => content
[:db_insert_placeholder_78] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_79] => -1
[:db_insert_placeholder_80] => user
[:db_insert_placeholder_81] => new
[:db_insert_placeholder_82] => seven
[:db_insert_placeholder_83] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_84] => 0
[:db_insert_placeholder_85] => dashboard_sidebar
[:db_insert_placeholder_86] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_87] => -1
[:db_insert_placeholder_88] => search
[:db_insert_placeholder_89] => form
[:db_insert_placeholder_90] => seven
[:db_insert_placeholder_91] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_92] => -10
[:db_insert_placeholder_93] => dashboard_sidebar
[:db_insert_placeholder_94] => 
[:db_insert_placeholder_95] => -1
)
in standard_install() (line 201 of /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/profiles/standard/standard.install).

#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/includes/database/database.inc(2171): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/includes/database/database.inc(683): DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array, Array)
#2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/includes/database/mysql/query.inc(36): DatabaseConnection->query('INSERT INTO {bl...', Array, Array)
#3 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/profiles/standard/standard.install(201): InsertQuery_mysql->execute()
#4 [internal function]: standard_install()
#5 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/includes/module.inc(866): call_user_func_array('standard_instal...', Array)
#6 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/includes/module.inc(477): module_invoke('standard', 'install')
#7 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/modules/simpletest/drupal_web_test_case.php(1498): module_enable(Array, false)
#8 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/sites/all/modules/my_module/my_module.test(26): DrupalWebTestCase->setUp('my_module')
#9 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/modules/simpletest/drupal_web_test_case.php(501): MyModuleMenuBlockTestCase->setUp()
#10 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/modules/simpletest/simpletest.module(178): DrupalTestCase->run()
#11 [internal function]: _simpletest_batch_operation(Array, '118', Array)
#12 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/includes/batch.inc(284): call_user_func_array('_simpletest_bat...', Array)
#13 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/includes/batch.inc(161): _batch_process()
#14 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/includes/batch.inc(80): _batch_do()
#15 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/modules/system/system.admin.inc(2373): _batch_page()
#16 [internal function]: system_batch_page()
#17 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/includes/menu.inc(517): call_user_func_array('system_batch_pa...', Array)
#18 /Library/WebServer/Documents/drupal7/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#19 {main}
```

The error only happens if my module is enabled, which is particularly strange because the error occurs in `DrupalWebTestCase::setUp` prior to any non-core modules being installed. Could something in my module be causing it to `setUp` more than once or loop back on itself somehow? My module implements the following hooks:

- hook_install
- hook_uninstall
- hook_menu
- hook_block_list_alter
- hook_drupal_goto_alter
- hook_theme
- hook_theme_registry_alter

My module also uses `features` to install certain block settings with the `fe_block` module in `features_extras` and has the following dependencies:

- fe_block
- features
- menu
- some other custom modules

The other custom modules are all thoroughly tested now and this issue does not occur if only they are installed. They include an implementation of `hook_watchdog`, `hook_element_info`, various additional API for forms, API for communication with an external web service, and account object manipulation using the latter API (primarily with `hook_user_presave`).

Has anybody got an idea what is causing my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To really figure out what's going on I'd have to dig deep into the `features` and `fe_block` modules, which I started to do and decided I *could* spend the next week digging and *still* not find any answers. So I tried enabling the module with the `fe_block` feature *after* setup, like so:

```
class MyModuleTestCase extends DrupalWebTestCase {

  // ...

  function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    // Enable my_module.module after setup is finished to avoid problems
    // with fe_block being enabled during initial installation.
    $success = module_enable(array('my_module'), TRUE);
    $this->assertTrue($success, 'Enabled modules: my_module');
    $this->resetAll();

    // ...
  }
```

Doing it this way got rid of the error, although for some reason one of the tests is taking *forever* to execute.